# Proving something is strict stationary

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Let $W$  be a uniform distribution on $(0,\pi)$. Let $Z_t=\cos(tw)$. I know that $Z_t$ is a strict stationary but I have no idea how to prove this. Can someone give me some methods?

Answer (score 0):

Since you assume $t$ to be a natural number and properties of $\cos$ it can be shown that $Z_t$ and $Z_{1}$ are equivalent.  For $Z_2$, you practically have two $Z_1$ and you toss a coin which one of them to select. Anyway, you have $Z_1$ at the end. Similartly for $t>2$.